# PHP Validating Form

Tags: php

I am having trouble showing the output that i called in printf in php tutorial. I just followed the tutorial but still can't figure out what is wrong in displaying the variables inside the printf in localhost. Is anyone can help me. Thank you.

```
    <?php
            $name = '';
            $password = '';
            $gender = '';
            $color = '';
            $languages = [];
            $comments = '';
            $tc = '';
        
           if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
                    $name = $_POST['name'];
                };
                if (isset($_POST['password'])) {  
                    $password = $_POST['password'];
                };
                if (isset($_POST['gender'])) {
                    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
                };
                if (isset($_POST['color'])) {
                    $color = $_POST['color'];
                };
                if (isset($_POST['languages'])) {
                    $languages = $_POST['languages'];
                };
                if (isset($_POST['comments'])) {
                    $comments = $_POST['comments'];
                };
                if (isset($_POST['tc'])) {
                    $tc = $_POST['tc'];
                };
            //here's the problem i cant resolve printing out the output//
            printf('User name: %s
                <br>Password: %s
                <br>Gender: %s
                <br>Color: %s
                <br>Language(s): %s
                <br>Comments: %s
                <br>T&amp;C: %s',
                htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES),
                htmlspecialchars($password, ENT_QUOTES),
                htmlspecialchars($gender, ENT_QUOTES),
                htmlspecialchars($color, ENT_QUOTES),
                htmlspecialchars(implode('', $languages), ENT_QUOTES),
                htmlspecialchars($comments, ENT_QUOTES),
                htmlspecialchars($tc, ENT_QUOTES));
        
                
            }
        ?>
        
        
        <form action="" 
            method="post">
              User name:  <input type="text" name="name"><br>
              Password:  <input type="password" value="password"><br>
              Gender:
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="f"> female
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m"> male
              <input type="radio" name="gender" value="o"> other<br/>
              Favorite color:
              <select name="color">
                <option value="">Please select</option>
                <option value="#f00">red</option>
                <option value="#0f0">green</option>
                <option value="#00f">blue</option>
        </select><br>
            Languages spoken:
            <select name="languages[]"multiple size="3">
                <option value="en">English</option>
                <option value="fr">French</option>
                <option value="it">Italian</option>
                </select><br>
                Comments: <textarea name="comments"></textarea><br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tc" value="ok"> I accept the T&amp;C<br> 
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
        
        </form>`
```

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? Are you getting an error message? No output? The wrong output?

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` - will never be true, you do not have any form field with that _name_.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` there is no any form field with the name `submit` and it will never become true to execute. **Remove the if Condition with submit or Else give the sumbit button name as Submit**

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Errors in your previous code are:

1. No semicolons `;` are needed after ending `if` statements.
2. No `name` attribute is specified for **password** input in the form.
3. Posting form data as `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}` without specifying the `name="submit"` attribute in the form.
4. Invalid use of `implode` function which will generate output be like `enfrit` or vice versa.

##### Additional Tips

5. Add the `required` attribute to each `input` to prevent from sending empty form data.
6. You have already specified `method="post"` in the form tag so, no need for validating each input field as `if (isset($_POST['fieldname'])) {...}` . `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}` will send all the form data as `POST` method.

And lastly, here is your updated code.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = '';
    $password = '';
    $gender = '';
    $color = '';
    $languages = [];
    $comments = '';
    $tc = '';

    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['gender'])) {
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['color'])) {
        $color = $_POST['color'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['languages'])) {
        $languages = $_POST['languages'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        $comments = $_POST['comments'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['tc'])) {
        $tc = $_POST['tc'];
    }

    //print output
    printf('User name: %s
    <br>Password: %s
    <br>Gender: %s
    <br>Color: %s
    <br>Language(s): %s
    <br>Comments: %s
    <br>T &amp; C: %s
    <br><br>',
    htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES),
    htmlspecialchars($password, ENT_QUOTES),
    htmlspecialchars($gender, ENT_QUOTES),
    htmlspecialchars($color, ENT_QUOTES),
    htmlspecialchars(implode(', ', $languages), ENT_QUOTES),
    htmlspecialchars($comments, ENT_QUOTES),
    htmlspecialchars($tc, ENT_QUOTES));
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    User name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password">
    <br>
    Gender:
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="f"> female
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m"> male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="o"> other
    <br>
    Favorite color:
    <select name="color">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="#f00">red</option>
        <option value="#0f0">green</option>
        <option value="#00f">blue</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Languages spoken:
    <select name="languages[]" multiple size="3">
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="fr">French</option>
        <option value="it">Italian</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Comments: <textarea name="comments"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tc" value="ok"> I accept the T &amp; C
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```